# Ошибка при обработке диаграммы в Pygal

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
   import requests

    import pygal
    from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS

    # создание вызова API и сохранение ответа
    url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

    r = requests.get(url)
    print('Status Code:', r.status_code)

    # сохранение ответа API в переменной 
    response_dict = r.json()
    print('Total repositories:', response_dict['total_count'])

    # Анализ информации о репозиториях
    repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

    names, plot_dicts = [], []
    for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
        names.append(repo_dict['name']) 

        plot_dict = {
        'value' : repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label' : repo_dict['description'],
        'xlink' : repo_dict['html_url']
        }
        plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

    # построение визуализации
    my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
    my_config = pygal.Config()
    my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
    my_config.show_legend = False
    my_config.title_font_size = 24
    my_config.label_font_size = 14
    my_config.major_label_font_size = 18
    my_config.truncate_label = 15
    my_config.show_y_guides = False
    my_config.width = 1000

    chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)

    chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
    chart.x_labels = names

    chart.add('', plot_dicts)
    chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

А затем ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\API_works\python_repos.py", line 48, in <module>
    chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 114, in render_to_file
    f.write(self.render(is_unicode=True, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 52, in render
    self.setup(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\base.py", line 217, in setup
    self._draw()
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\graph.py", line 933, in _draw
    self._plot()
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 146, in _plot
    self.bar(serie)
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 116, in bar
    metadata)
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\util.py", line 233, in decorate
    metadata['label'])
  File "C:\Users\warfan.Home\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygal\_compat.py", line 61, in to_unicode
    return string.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**Почему-то метод в библиотеке Pygal возвращает экземпляр None.**

**Также будет принят ответ - "Это баг Pygal"**

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS

# создание вызова API и сохранение ответа
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(url)
print('Status Code:', r.status_code)

# сохранение ответа API в переменной
response_dict = r.json()
print('Total repositories:', response_dict['total_count'])

# Анализ информации о репозиториях
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])

    plot_dict = {
    'value' : repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
    'label' : repo_dict['description'],
    'xlink' : repo_dict['html_url']
    }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

# построение визуализации
my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
my_config = pygal.Config()
my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.show_legend = False
my_config.title_font_size = 24
my_config.label_font_size = 14
my_config.major_label_font_size = 18
my_config.truncate_label = 15
my_config.show_y_guides = False
my_config.width = 1000

chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)

chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

print(plot_dicts[0]['value'])

chart.add('', plot_dicts[0]['value'])
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```